# Generating and signing a transaction - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: raw-transaction, signature, transaction-propagation

I am writing a program in c++ for generating and signing transactions. The transaction it generates seem to be invalid. Every time I try to broadcast it, I get an error saying insufficient funds on sender address.

```
RLP rlp;
uint8_t *privatekey = charArrayToByteArray("*******************************************");

TX tx;
tx.nonce="0x06";
tx.gasPrice="0x01a13b8600";
tx.gasLimit="0x5208";
tx.to="0x8f9ad0411a887c3243bcded341ed63f90b3e1417";
tx.value="0x2386f26fc10000";
tx.data="0x";
tx.v="";
tx.r="";
tx.s="";

string enc = rlp.bytesToHex(rlp.encode(tx, true)); //Encode raw transaction

uint8_t *hashval = new uint8_t[HASH_LENGTH];
keccak256((uint8_t*)enc.c_str(), enc.size(), hashval); //Generate hash

uint8_t* signature = new uint8_t[SIGNATURE_LENGTH];
uECC_sign(privatekey,hashval, HASH_LENGTH, signature, uECC_secp256k1()); //Sign the hash

uint8_t *r = new uint8_t[32];
uint8_t *s = new uint8_t[32];
splitArray(signature,r,0,32);
splitArray(signature,s,32,64);

tx.r = string("0x") + byteArrayToCharArray(r, 32);
tx.s = string("0x") + byteArrayToCharArray(s, 32);
tx.v = "0x1c";

string encoded = rlp.bytesToHex(rlp.encode(tx, false)); //Encode transaction with signature
```

uECC library: https://github.com/kmackay/micro-ecc/blob/master/uECC.h

RLP library: https://github.com/kvhnuke/Ethereum-Arduino/blob/master/Ethereum-Arduino/RLP.cpp

Resulting transaction: http://ehrs.info/images/g7HkznUS3C.png

Comment: I got this problem too, after this problem I try to using r,s and "1b" as v construct my TX through Ethereum-tx, and using getSenderAddress() to verify "sender address" I got a wrong sender

Comment: The problem was in the RLP library that I was using. I made some edits to it and it started generating the correct transactions. Here's the completed project: https://github.com/Kidades/hwwallet , you can take the RLP library from there.

Comment: It still just uses 1b for the v value though, which is not always correct.

Comment: in my case, I'm building a usb cold wallet device, raw transaction and keccak256(SHA3) hash is generate in browser side.

so that my device just doing "sign" process, and only put "r", "s" result from device into RLP of browser side code

i tried sign process in browser is fine, but using micro-ecc got wrong

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29113)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29113)

Answer (score 3):

Your raw transaction before the first RLP encoding needs the `chain ID` in place of the empty `v` value per [EIP155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md).

Then afterwards, you replace the `v` with `(chainID << 1) + 35`, and the `r & s` with their respective values from the signature. Finally, another RLPEncoding of this object gives you the final transaction data.

Not having done this is why you're getting the `No funds` errors, since the chain your transaction is destined for can't be fathomed properly from the signed transaction data blob.